# Azure: How to assign a Reserved IP to a new/existing machine?

Tags: azure, ip, azure-networking

What I am trying to do is configure my VM such that it doesn't lose the public IP between restarts.
I have created a Reserved IP:
[image: my reserved ip]
I've tried this both with an existing VM and while create a new VM but I am unable to select my reserved IP:
[image: trying, for a new machine]

- The Reserved IP is in the same Subscription and Location as the VM
- The Reserved IP and VM are in the same Resource Group
- I am unable to see the subnet of the Reserved IP but if I had the option of setting that up during deployment of that IP, I am 100% sure I would have selected the same subnet
- I am aware of: [How to assign a reserved / static public IP Address to a virtual machine on Azure](https://serverfault.com/questions/674240/how-to-assign-a-reserved-static-public-ip-address-to-a-virtual-machine-on-azur)

  - However, that question is outdated and even the more recent updates to the answer refer to broken links
- I am also aware of the IP configuration for a public ip but not sure what it does (is this what I need, rather than a reserved IP?):
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Reserved IP-addresses is a classic feature so you won't be able to pick those IP's. Create a new public IP from the "Public IP addresses" tab in Azure.
If you want to keep your IP after reboots or deallocation, make it static.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have already applied this but wasn't sure it's the correct solution, as there's also the concept of "Reserved IP", which I know now is something from a different realm.
PS: do you know how they charge for Reserved IP? I wasn't able to see the price when deploying or in my billing analysis

Comment: I will test this solution for a couple of days and accept your answer if it works

Comment: In ASM deployment model, there is no charge for instance level public IP (ILPIP) addresses when the virtual machine is stopped-deallocated (reserved ip's is ASM). https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/reserved-ip-addresses/